# fast port scanner on php

Tags: php, port

Can someone show an example of how to make a scanner of all ports on a server (by ip address), for open ports? I tried to do it through fsockopen, but it turned out to be very slow, it scans about 1,000 ports in 5 minutes. But I saw others how the scanner looked for all the ports in 1 minute, but it was on a nodeJS, is this possible on a php?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of PHP use *bash*:

```php
//$output = shell_exec('netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN');
$output = <<<DEMO_OUTPUT
tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          43385      1821/cupsd  
tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          44064      1823/sshd 
DEMO_OUTPUT;

$output = explode("\n", $output);
$ips = [];

foreach($output as $o) {
    $ips[] = preg_split('/\s+/', $o)[3];
}
```

and then just parse output

Comment: I need in another server check ports, not local